# How to measure only the hoizontal component of distance between nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to establish lines to show geometry of pages. I want to measure only the horizontal component between `current page text area.west` and `current page.west`. The line show distances should be connecting `current page text area.west` `current page` in horizontal manner as shown

[image]

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}

\newlength{\widthpageframe}
\setlength{\widthpageframe}{0.1mm}
\newcommand{\opacitypageframe}{0.1}
\newcommand{\pageframeMainText}[2]{%c
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay] {
        
        \draw [color=gray, line width=#1, opacity=#2]
        (current page text area.south west)
        rectangle
        (current page text area.north east);
        
    }
}

\begin{document}
    
    \pageframeMainText{\widthpageframe}{\opacitypageframe}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, arrows={Latex[length=11pt]}-{Latex[length=11pt]}]
        \draw[] let \p1 = ($(current page.west) - (current page text area.west)$), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in (current page.west) --  node[above, sloped] {\n1} (current page text area.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: The value `\x1` *is* already only the horizontal component. You might need to `abs` it in case it's negative. (Or `veclen(\x1,0pt)` but that seems unnecessary overkill.)

Comment: Thanks. This solves the issue of horizontal component. Is it possible to draw the line horizontally?

Comment: Yes, either use a relative coordinate with `\x1` directly, i.e. `(current page.west) --+(right:\x1)` or just use `(current page.west)--(current page.west-|current page text area.west)` if that's all you need. See [the manual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#sec-13.3.1) for what that's about.